# Creating a Dark Scene with only a glowing lamp and a Character - What HDR/World settings and material settings for light are required

Tags: materials, lighting

This is quite an open ended question, but i would like any possible help. I want to make a scene like in the image shared below. [image]

[image]
I am not going for photo realism, my 3d character will be used in place of the woman here. To get this effect, i have added volume scatter in world settings and added glare node in composite to get a glow. But as you can see my render is far away from the result i want. I want to know if this can be done in Blender and what settings should i use to get the backround lamp and well lit character. From what i can see, currently my lamp illuminates a lot of the scene and environment, while in the pic only the character is lit and the lamp glow is seen, rest of the environment is black.

[image]
[image]

Comment: maybe don't use volume scatter and instead create the glare effect in the Compositor?

Comment: I would definitely not use volume scatter here. Only use a _Glare_ node in the _Compositor_. The other thig you can clearly see is that there is a light source from the front, as the lamp in the background might create the rim lighting, but never cast light onto her face and the other parts of her body that are on the opposite side of the lamp.

Comment: Current glare effect is using the compositor only. I am not able to get the pitch black darkness though

Comment: Of course not if you use volume scatter - as the name says, it scatters the light inside the volume. Meaning there is nothing pitch black unless the density of the volume is so high that the light doesn't reach through. But then this will definitely not help your scene ;)

Comment: Apart from that, what do you know about the reference photo, how it was taken? To me it looks like there was bright light shining on her, then maybe shot with a low exposure and cranking up the contrast to get the dark parts black. So did you set the _Color Management_ settings to resemble that? High contrast, bright lights, low exposure? Then I guess the original photo was edited afterwards, so you can further work on it in compositing or also in an external image editor additionally.

Comment: These photos look like they were heavily edited in post prod softwares like photoshop, lightroom or after effects. I would use your scene and play with the compositor nodes or the color management settings if you want to approach it, because you won't get this effect with "just" a physically based renderer

Comment: Oh, it's the big teddy bear again! :-)  With a real camera, you can take such a picture (without the rim light) with a flash lamp in a dim room with only a few lamps/light sources. In Blender, you can recreate this effect as *Gorgious* and *moonboots* suggested. Here is a try:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJOtS.jpg The ground is "fake" because it's painted almost pitchback (no realistic green grass)

Comment: @Blunder And I suggested that, too... ;)

Comment: oops, of course you did :D

Comment: The opic is not mine actually, i got it from internet and like the setting, so trying to approximate it. I will try the things you mentioned above, thanks.

Comment: @Blunder can you please share the settings you made for the shared render pic.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my second try:
[image: second try]
(Note that you can copy (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) & paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) all three `[X, Y, Z]` values at once in Blender when you hover the location field and press the keys.)

The following changes were made:

- *World* settings: removed the *Volumne Scatter* node (=no more fog), set *Color* to pure black (`000000`)
- Floor plane: made it less reflective and darker by setting the *Color* of the *Diffuse* node to Hex `080808`, and *Roughness* to `1`.
- lowered the *Strength* of the Light disc (*Circle* object) from 300 to `1` (*Emission* node). It's important that it emits some light, but it doesn't take much since we're making it glow in the *Compositor*.
- added an *Empty* and called it *Light Focus* to control the lights and placed it in the bear's face, position `[2.550, 4.250, 2.710]`
- move the *Spot* light to position `[6.063, 9.141, 3.256]` (in front of the bear), set *Strength* to `1200 W`, added a *Damped Track* object constraint with the *Light Focus* as target and set *Track Axis* to `-Z` so the light points to where the *Empty* is => spotlight on the bear. See the screenshot below.
- added an *Area* light as background light behind the bear and opposite of the camera at position `[-2.188, -1.135, 4.279]`, set *Strength* to `3000 W`, set *Size* to `2 m`. Then added a *Damped Track* object constraint with the *Light Focus* as target, *Track Axis* to `-Z`
  [image: light positions]
- enabled `[X]` *Depth Of Field* in the *Object Data Properties* tab of the camera, choosen the *Light Focus* as *Focus Object*.
- in the *Render Properties* tab, enabled `[X]` *Motion Blur* for the raindrops
- the raindrops (*Sphere* object) had no material yet. Created a new simple glass material for them => set Transmission = `1.0`, and *Roughness* = `0.067` in the *Principled BSDF* node. If you wish, you can stretch the mesh a little to better mimic the falling motion.
- in the *View Layer Properties* tab enabled *Passes > Light > Other* `[X]` *Emission* for the *Compositor*
- almost done. Switched to the *Compositing* workspace, enabled `[X]` *Use Nodes* option and added the following nodes:
  [image: compositor nodes]
- last but not least, zoomed out a little with the camera so that the foot does not "stick" to the bottom of the picture.

Here is my first try, just for comparison. The eyes look different because the *Separate Color* node changed in one of the recent Blender 3.x versions and the node was "invalid" in my Blender 3.3.

The front light is stronger and the angle is different. The light comes more from the side. *Lens Distortion* is stronger (3000 W). The camera and raindrops are unchanged.

[image: first try]

Have fun experimenting with it!

Comment: THank you so much :D